# Nuget PCL library conflict

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, portable-class-library

I'm using Nito.Async both in a PCL framework library and in client app which uses the library. The PCL lib targets .Net4.5 & SL5, and the client is .Net4.5.

If I don't reference Nito.Async in client app, everything is fine. But if I reference it, when i run the app, an `MissingMethodException` occurs :

```
 Method not found: 'Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1<!0> Nito.AsyncEx.AwaitableDisposable`1.GetAwaiter()'
```

After digging a little more, it seems the problem is msbuild copy the Nito lib from `portable-net40` referenced by the PCL lib in the target \bin folder, and then, copy the Nito lib from `net45` referenced by the client in the target \bin. So it overwrites the first portable Nito.Async DLL... And when I launch the app, the `portable-net40` is replaced by the `net45`.

The only few options I see are :

- Directly include Nito.Async source in my library, but it means loosing the Nuget advantage of having up-to-date libs...
- Ask Stephen Cleary to rename his DLL for .Net45 target to something like `Nito.AsyncEx.Net45.dll` instead of `Nito.AsyncEx.dll` (and do it for each distinct target), but I doubt it's a perfect solution.

How can I handle this kind of DLL conflict ?

Is there something on the Nuget or MsBuild side already made for this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portable version is supposed to be replaced by the `net45` version in this case.  The MissingMethodException you get means that there's an API compatibility bug in the Nito.AsyncEx package.

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/77b9711c2c5fd4ca28b220ce4c93d209eeca2b4a/Source/Nito.AsyncEx%20(NET45%2C%20Win8%2C%20WP8%2C%20WPA81)/AwaitableDisposable.cs), I'm not sure there's a way to fix this.  `GetAwaiter()` returns a `TaskAwaiter<T>`, but that type has a different identity (it's in a different namespace) for portable libraries targeting Silverlight or .NET 4.  I think this was necessary because the constructor is internal so we had to reimplement the class for the portable async support for platforms that didn't have it already.

The simplest fix for this would be to drop support for any platforms which don't already support async from the PCL.  So you could target .NET 4.5, WP8, WP8.1, and Windows 8 store apps.

Comment: @sharped I've filed an issue about this on the AsyncEx project: https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/issues/13

Comment: For those who cannot retarget solution to .NET 4.5, replace `Nito.Async` library with solution described in Stephen's blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266983.aspx and 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx